# Safari - fixed navbar shows up parcially until scroll animation is over

Tags: html, css, ipad, mobile-safari, translate-animation

I got a well placed `position:absolute` header (with gradient & transform3d to do a nice animation - to make the header smoothly go down ~80px) and when I hit ~150px of scroll, I change his position to `fixed` - doing the animation.

In Safari mobile, when the animation is done, only 50% of the navbar shows up, sticking to the top of the page. The other 50% only shows up when I completely stop the scroll animation & remove my finger off the screen. I've applied `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` and `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);` to enable hardware acceleration but the result stays the same. The .navbar is a .row, with 2 inside divs that are basically the same, soo I suppose the problem is not not the children elements. 
This only happens on my iPad.

Here's some code:

CSS

```
.nav_bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 52px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transition: transform .3s ease;

    z-index: 2;

   .&.is-fixed  {
        position: fixed;
        top: -80px;

        transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
        box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

        &:before {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;

            background-color:$bright-turquoise;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, $cobalt 50%, $bright-turquoise 100%);

            content: '';
   }
}
```

JS (CoffeScript)

```
(window).scroll ->
  scroll = $(window).scrollTop()
  windowWidth = $(window).width()

  if windowWidth >= 1024
    if scroll >= $('.area_1').height()and
    scroll < $('.footer').offset().top - 150
      $navbar.addClass 'is-fixed'
    else if scroll < $('.area_1').height() || scroll > $('.footer').offset().top - 150 
      setTimeout (->
        $navBar.removeClass 'is-fixed'
        return
      ), navAnimationTimer
    return
```

Anyone had the same problem or knows the solution?

Comment: without any relevant code. we can't help you

Comment: @MihaiT just added the code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to give the header a `will-change` attribute? Maybe this way Safari watches for changes (better).
I've noticed this behaviour on several pages, and even other (mobile) browsers.
My general workaround was always to make the header fixed in the beginning so the browser won't have to rerender everything.

Comment: Tryed to do that, but still doesn't work. The problem remains the same. It's like only 50% would render... When I stop scrolling, he renders the 100% and after that, I can go absolute position and position fixed again, and he'll render the 100%. The problem is just about the first time.

Comment: even when it's positoned fixed right from the beginning?

Comment: No, at the beginning if the header is 'fixed' everything goes fine. The problem is about this transaction of 'absolute' to 'fixed'. When 'absolute', everything is ok, then I change to 'fixed', and while scrolling he should show up (ok, perfect, he shows up) but only renders 50% (the left half of the navbar)... When I stop the scroll and release my finger, he renders the 50% of the right side.

Comment: And your design doesn't allow to keep it fixed from the start right?
Can you create a little snippet with just this element?

Comment: No, I must change it from absolute to fixed. I'll replicate the element (to make 1 element fixed and the other absolute), and hide / show with the scroll event. TY for the help.